# Не работают виртуальные хосты

Tags: ubuntu

Содержание файла /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   asus-UX32A
127.0.2.1       smm
127.0.3.1       phpmyadmin
```

Содержание доп. конфигурации httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin
    DocumentRoot "/home/asus/www/localhost/"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.2.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin
    DocumentRoot "/home/asus/www/smm/"
    ServerName smm
    ErrorLog "logs/smm-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/smm-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.3.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin
    DocumentRoot "/home/asus/www/phpmyadmin/"
    ServerName phpmyadmin
    ErrorLog "logs/phpmyadmin-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/phpmyadmin-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Но если в строке браузера вбить один из адресов,phpmyadmin или smm то выводить всё равно корневой каталог /home/asus/www/
ЧТо я не учёл?заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: Всё поправил,оказывается конфиг забыл дополнительный раскомментировать.
P.S. с раскомментируемым конфигом одинаковые ip не прокатывают,поэтому нужны разные ip,иначе ведёт всех на первый виртуальный хост из представленных

Comment: Зкрывайте тему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<VirtualHost 127.0.3.1:80> а че тут столько айпишников?

попробуйте просто 
<VirtualHost  *:80>

Comment: Поменял,перезапустил apache,всё так же,показывает главный каталог.

Comment: ой а в hosts то зачем такие разные айпишники, сделайте всем 127.0.0.1

Comment: с одними точно не работает,все адреса выкидывают в www папку и не идут по подпапкам